# ReferenceError: serverQueue is not defined

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to implement the functionality of a music bot into my discord bot, but upon saving my work in atom, node reports that the phrase "serverQueue" is not defined.

Obviously the problem stems from the fact that the phrase "queue" was not defined earlier in the file and therefore it doesn't understand how to use it, only problem is, I don't know how to add it.

```
client.on("message", async message => {
if (message.author.bot) return;

const severQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

if (message.content.includes(`!play`)) {
    execute(message, serverQueue);
    return;
} else if (message.content.includes(`!skip`)) {
    skip(message, serverQueue);
    return;
} else if (message.content.includes(`!stop`)) {
    stop(message, serverQueue);
    return;
} else {
    message.channel.send("Necesitas poner un comando valido...");
}
});

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
    const args = message.content.split(" ");

    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!voiceChannel)
        return message.channel.send(
            "¡Necesitas estar en un canal de voz para pedir musica!"
        );
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsfor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has("CONNECT") || !permissions.has("SPEAK")) {
        return message.channel.send(
            "¡Necesito permisos para unirme y cantar en ese canal de voz!"
        );
    }

    const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
    const song = {
        title: songInfo.title,
        url: songInfo.video_url,
    };

    if (!serverQueue) {
        const queueContrucut = {
            textChannel: message.channel,
        voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
        connection: null,
        songs: [],
        volume: 5,
        playing: true,
        };

    queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContrucut);

    queueContrucut.songs.push(song);

    try {
        var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        queueContrucut.connection = connection;
     play(message.guild, queueContrucut.song[0]);
    }catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        queue.delete(message.guild.id);
        return message.channel.send(err);
    }
  } else {
    serverQueue.songs.push(song);
    console.log(serverQueue.song);
    return message.channel.send(`¡${song.title} ha sido agregada a la lista de reproducción!`);
  }
}

function skip(message, serverQueue) {
  if (!message.member.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(
        "¡Necesitas estar en un canal de voz para skipear la musica!"
    );
  if (!serverQueue)
    return message.channel.send("¡No hay canción que pueda skipear!");
  serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function stop (message, serverQueue) {
  if (!message.member.voice.channel)
    return message.channel.send(
        "¡Necesitas estar en un canal de voz para detener la musica!"
    );
  serverQueue.songs = [];
  serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
    if (!song) {
        serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
        .play(ytdl(song.url))
        .on("finish", () => {
          serverQueue.songs.shift();
          play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
        })
        .on("error", error => console.error(error));
     dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
     serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Empezó a sonar: **${song.title}**`);
}
```

It's expected to start up and allow me to connect it to a voice channel for audio playback from sites like YouTube for music listening, but instead, it crashes on startup and all I get is the error that the phrase "ServerQueue" is not defined.

This is the error that comes out in the console:
!play despacito
(node:7644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: serverQueue is not defined
at Client. (C:\Users\abrah\Documents\alienwalkerbot\index.js:101:22)
at Client.emit (events.js:326:22)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\abrah\Documents\alienwalkerbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\abrah\Documents\alienwalkerbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\abrah\Documents\alienwalkerbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\abrah\Documents\alienwalkerbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\abrah\Documents\alienwalkerbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\abrah\Documents\alienwalkerbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\abrah\Documents\alienwalkerbot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
(node:7644) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)

Comment: Right at the beginning, line 4 or so, there is a typo of `severQueue` instead of `serverQueue`. (`const severQueue = queue.get()...)

Comment: I thank you very much, after I got other errors of dependencies or undefined properties, but I already solved it, I was able to make it work : D!